# Angular using PrismJS - Line Numbers Not Showing

Tags: angular, prismjs

I am developing an app in Angular, which uses PrismJS to display some code sent dynamically, depending on the button selected. The following code displays the line numbers correctly.

```
<pre class="line-numbers" data-start="5">
 <code class="language-markup">
  &lt;div&gt;&lt;a data-icon="fa-file-o"&gt;File&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
 </code>
</pre>
```

[image]

But using the PrismJS like this will not show line numbers at all.

```
<pre class="line-numbers" data-start="5">
 <code class="language-markup" [innerHtml]="myCode">
 </code>
</pre>
```

[image]

Would really like to know why exactly this is happening, does the *Prism Line Numbers* plugin checks the block of line between the **code** tags? If so is there any way to pass the code dynamically using Angular and specify the starting line number?

Thanks